# Height differences on mobile vs desktop

Tags: mobile, height, desktop

I'm trying to nest an iframe inside a div to fix the height of the iframe by fixing the height of the div. 
My problem is the amount of the iframe that shows on a desktop browser is different from the amount that shows on a mobile browser (safari and chrome of iOS). It's like 3em on mobile does not equal 3em on desktop

Below is the div/iframe html:

```
<div name="iframe-div" style="height:3em; overflow:hidden; font-size:12px">
<iframe src="http://blog.mycitylives.com/2012/02/twn-links/" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" " width="90%" height="810px">
</iframe>
</div>
```

It's being displayed on the iframe src link above.

Answer (score 0):

the 'em' unit is a relative measurement, literally referring to the width/height of the 'm' character for the font type and font size.  so, i would expect the size of a mobile to naturally be smaller than a desktop.  the css interal to the iframe page may be causing conflicts as well.

try using pixels or a percentage instead.

Comment: I've tried using px, em and % they all result in different heights on mobile and desktop... ie the text doesn't get cut off on desktop but does on mobile

Comment: ah i think i see now 'overflow: hidden' on your div and the scrolling on the iframe.  at the page url above and dropping the code into another html page, the div is cutting off the iframe even on a desktop.  what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want the div to cut off the iframe after 3 lines on desktop and on mobile. Regardless of the height unit I use it cuts the iframe at different places.